# how to calculate p-value for 48 columns and save the results

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, p-value, storing-data

I have two 18-by-48 datasets. One for died people and the other for survived. Both have the same column names(CNP1,CNP2,...,CNP48). I would like to calculate the P-value of each CNP. 
The function that I am using is the following:

> t.test(died_CNP$CNP1,survived_CNP$CNP1)[3]
>   - How can I use this function for the 48 columns at one go and save the results in variables ( p1,p2,...,p48)?

Answer (score 0):

You can just loop over the columns.

```
 pVals <- numeric()
 for(i in 1:ncol(died_CNP))
   pVals[i] <- t.test(died_CNP[,i],survived_CNP[,i])$p.value
```

The resulting `pVals` will be a numeric vector of length `48`. It is recommended to adjust your p-values using [`p.adjust`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/p.adjust.html) to avoid the  [multiple comparisons problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_comparisons_problem)

```
 pValsAdjusted <- p.adjust(pVals)
```

Comment: How to do the same thing using python

Answer (score 0):

This is too long for a comment, but extends Gregor's answer. The key difference is it constructs the `for` loop without growing the object.

```
pVals  <- vector ("numeric", length = ncol (died_CNP))
for (i in seq_along (pVals)){
  pVals[i] <- t.test(died_CNP[[i]], survived_CNP[[i]])$p.value
}
```

Or you can vectorize it

```
pVals <- vapply (seq_along (died_CNP),
          function (i){
            t.test(died_CNP[,i],survived_CNP[,i])$p.value
          },
          numeric(1))
```

(Typed on a phone, code untested)

Comment: How to do the same thing using python

Comment: I'm afraid I can't answer that for you. You may want to post a question tagged with python and link to this question.

Comment: I want this for myself :)